# Jasmine how pass specs that run in any order that depend on a closure variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I feel like this should be really intuitive... but maybe it doesn't work the same way I'm used to thinking of it in Rspec... Here's the function I'm trying to test:

```
var finalSet = (function() {
  var mount = false

  return {
    initializePage: function() {
      if (mount == false) {
        this.mountForm();
        mount = true;
      }
      this.greetCustomer();
    },
    greetCustomer: function() {
      ...
    },
    mountForm: function() {
      ...
    }
  }
})();
```

The gist is that `mount` is a closure variable that ensures that regardless how many times `initializePage` is called, `mountForm` is only called once.

This is my current spec:

```
describe("finalSet", function() {
  describe("initializePage", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      spyOn(finalSet, "mountForm")
      spyOn(finalSet, "greetCustomer")
    })
    describe("first initialization", function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        finalSet.initializePage();
      })
      it("calls both methods", function() {
        expect(finalSet.mountForm).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(finalSet.greetCustomer).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
      describe("initialize again", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
          finalSet.initializePage();
        })
        it("repeat calls only greetCustomer", function() {
          expect(finalSet.mountForm.calls.count()).toEqual(1)
          expect(finalSet.greetCustomer.calls.count()).toEqual(2)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

If I run the specs individually, they pass. Together, and at random, only 1 will pass, the first spec that is run, the second will always fail.

I know why this is happening... but not the appropriate Jasmine set up to fix this issue.

The reason it's happening is because `finalSet` mounts once across all specs, meaning the closure is set once despite there being two specs. So what happens is that if the `"first initialization"` test runs first, the `beforeEach` call to `finalSet.initializePage()` sets the `mount = true`, this first spec passes, but then, come the `"initialize again" test,` mount`is still true, it doesn't reset, so neither of the 2`beforeEach`calls to`finalSet.initializePage()`will ever call`mountForm`, since that happened in the first spec that passed. Hence the second spec fails.

On the other hand, if `"initialize again"` runs first, the stacked 2 `beforeEach` calls to `finalSet.initializePage()` work as expected, `mountForm` is called once, `greetCustomer` is called twice. But then when the first `"first initialization"` spec is called, `mount = true` already, so nothing gets called.

The immediate question: is there a way to reset the closure as part of the first `beforeEach`?

The larger question: I'm used to this kind of nested speccing from Rspec, but... I'm feeling like maybe this is NOT how one should test in Jasmine, so very open to what a better way of testing this would be is.

Thanks!

Comment: Why use the same instance for both tests?

Comment: you mean the same instance of `finalSet`?

Comment: Yes, the object in question. My point is that the way the tests are now conflates two concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to test what’s essentially a global object across multiple specs. You’ll modify your code in some way to test what you want. Here are some ideas:

1. Add a reset() function to the exported object that sets the mount variable to false, Call this function in a before/afterEach in your specs. This is similar to how you might reset a database (a global resource) in a Rails spec before every test.
2. Have your code return a function instead of immediately invoking it. You might rename the finalSet variable as createFinalSet. This means you have a finalSet factory instead of a global instance or singleton; each test would have its own finalSet via `finalSet = createFinalSet()`.

Comment: ok I went with #1. That was what I would've expected to be done automatically, maybe that's also a flawed understanding of Rspec. Like I was expecting each spec to load the file separately so that `finalSet` would be invoked just for that spec (and thus closure variable would auto-reset)